# adding dynamically added table row values into database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

hi i am working on a form which has a table whic adds rows on a button click 
but my problem is when i add a new row the counter value goes to 12 instead of getting 2 can anyone help me out 
here is my code

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
    header("Location: unauthorize_access.php");
}
require("includes/dbconnect.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>Makhtab</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form2/view.css" media="all">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="form2/view.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="form2/calendar.js"></script>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript"> 
                    <script type="text/javascript">

                        function deleteRow(row)
                        {
                            var i=row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
                            document.getElementById('POITable').deleteRow(i);
                        }


                        function insRow()
                        {
                            console.log( 'hi');
                            var x=document.getElementById('POITable');
                            var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
                            var len = x.rows.length;
                            new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

                            var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
                            inp1.id += len;
                            inp1.value = '';
                            var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
                            inp2.id += len;
                            inp2.value = '';
                            x.appendChild( new_row );
                        }
                    </script>
                    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                        var i=1;
                        function addRow()
                        {
                            var tbl = document.getElementById('zimtable');
                            var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
                            var iteration = lastRow - 1;
                            var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

                            var firstCell = row.insertCell(0);
                            var el = document.createElement('input');
                            el.type = 'text';
                            el.name = 'zimname_' + i;
                            el.id = 'zimname_' + i;
                            el.size = 40;
                            el.maxlength = 40;
                            firstCell.appendChild(el);

                            var secondCell = row.insertCell(1);
                            var el2 = document.createElement('input');
                            el2.type = 'text';
                            el2.name = 'zimmob_' + i;
                            el2.id = 'zimmob_' + i;
                            el2.size = 13;
                            el2.maxlength = 13;
                            secondCell.appendChild(el2);


                            // alert(i);
                            i++;
                            makhtab.h.value=i;
                              alert(i);
                        }
                    </script>
                    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                        var i=1;
                        function addalRow()
                        {
                            var tbl = document.getElementById('alimtable');
                            var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
                            var iteration = lastRow - 1;
                            var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

                            var firstCell = row.insertCell(0);
                            var el = document.createElement('input');
                            el.type = 'text';
                            el.name = 'alimname_' + i;
                            el.id = 'alimname_' + i;
                            el.size = 40;
                            el.maxlength = 40;
                            firstCell.appendChild(el);

                            var secondCell = row.insertCell(1);
                            var el2 = document.createElement('input');
                            el2.type = 'text';
                            el2.name = 'alimmob_' + i;
                            el2.id = 'alimmob_' + i;
                            el2.size = 13;
                            el2.maxlength = 13;
                            secondCell.appendChild(el2);

                            var thirdCell = row.insertCell(2);
                            var element4 = document.createElement("select");
                            element4.name ='qabil_'+i;
                            var option1 = document.createElement("option");
                            option1.value='MUFTI';
                            option1.innerHTML='MUFTI';
                            element4.appendChild(option1);

                            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
                            option2.value='AALIM';
                            option2.innerHTML='AALIM';              
                            element4.appendChild(option2);

                            var option3 = document.createElement("option");
                            option3.value='QARI';
                            option3.innerHTML='QARI';               
                            element4.appendChild(option3);

                            var option4 = document.createElement("option");
                            option4.value='HAFIZ';
                            option4.innerHTML='HAFIZ';              
                            element4.appendChild(option3);

                            thirdCell.appendChild(element4);

                            // alert(i);
                            i++;
                            makhtab.r.value=i;
                              alert(i);
                        }
                    </script>


                <!--<style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
                    @import "tran/css/layout-styles.css";
                    @import "tran/css/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css";
                </style>-->
                    <script  type="text/javascript" src="tran/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
                    <script  type="text/javascript" src="tran/js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js"></script>

                    <script  type="text/javascript" src="tran/js/jq-ac-script.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">

                        //   function checkForm()
                        // {
                        //     if(makhtab.code.value == "") {
                        //       alert("Error: Code cannot be Empty!");
                        //     makhtab.code.focus();
                        //   return false;
                        // }
                        //   if(makhtab.name.value == "") {
                        //     alert("Error: Name cannot be Empty!");
                        //   makhtab.name.focus();
                        //  return false;
                        //}
                        //if(makhtab.cmbcount.value == "") {
                        //  alert("Error: Country cannot be Empty!");
                        //makhtab.cmbcount.focus();
                        // return false;
                        // }
                        //if(makhtab.cmbstate.value == "") {
                        //  alert("Error: State cannot be Empty!");
                        //makhtab.cmbstate.focus();
                        // return false;
                        // }

                        /* if(makhtab.cmbteh.value == "") {
                                alert("Error: Tehsil cannot be Empty!");
                                makhtab.cmbteh.focus();
                                return false;
                            } 
                            if(makhtab.cmbcity.value == "") {
                                alert("Error: City cannot be Empty!");
                                makhtab.cmbcity.focus();
                                return false;
                            } 
                            if(makhtab.tel.value == "") {
                                alert("Error: Telephone cannot be Empty!");
                                makhtab.tel.focus();
                                return false;
                            }
                            if(makhtab.mob.value == "") {
                                alert("Error: Mobile cannot be Empty!");
                                makhtab.mob.focus();
                                return false;
                            } 

                            if(makhtab.stu.value == "") {
                                alert("Error: Students cannot be Empty!");
                                makhtab.stu.focus();
                                return false;
                            }


                        }*/

                    </script>
                    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
                        <!--
                        pic1 = new Image(16, 16); 
                        pic1.src = "loader.gif";

                        $(document).ready(function(){

                            $("#code").change(function() { 

                                var code = $("#code").val();

                                if(code.length >= 4)
                                {
                                    $("#status").html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');

                                    $.ajax({  
                                        type: "POST",  
                                        url: "check_ct.php",  
                                        data: "code="+ code,  
                                        success: function(msg){  

                                            $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){ 

                                                if(msg == 'OK')
                                                { 
                                                    $("#code").removeClass('object_error'); // if necessary
                                                    $("#code").addClass("object_ok");
                                                    $(this).html('&nbsp;<img src="tick.gif" align="absmiddle">');
                                                }  
                                                else  
                                                {  
                                                    $("#code").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
                                                    $("#code").addClass("object_error");
                                                    $(this).html(msg);
                                                }  

                                            });

                                        } 

                                    }); 

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $("#status").html('<font color="red">The code should have at least <strong>4</strong> characters.</font>');
                                    $("#code").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
                                    $("#code").addClass("object_error");
                                }

                            });

                        });

                        //-->
                    </SCRIPT>
                    </head>
                    <body id="main_body" >

                        <div id="form_container">
                            <form id="makhtab" class="appnitro" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"  onsubmit="return checkForm()" action="submit2.php">
                                <div class="form_description">
                                    <br />
                                    <h2>Makhtab Details</h2>
                                    <!--<p>This is your form description. Click here to edit.</p>-->
                                </div>                      
                                <table border="0px" width="100%">

                                    <tr>
                                        <td><label class="description" for="element_1">Code</label></td><td><input id="element_1"  id="code" name="code" class="element text small" type="text" maxlength="6" value=""/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><label class="description" for="element_1">Name</label></td><td><input id="element_1" name="name" class="element text large" type="text" maxlength="40" value=""/> </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td><label class="description" for="element_1">Address</label></td><td><input id="element_4_1" name="add1" class="element text large" value="" type="text"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td><td><input id="element_4_1" name="add2" class="element text large" value="" type="text"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td><td><input id="element_4_1" name="add3" class="element text large" value="" type="text"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><label class="description" for="element_1">City</label></td><td><select name="cmbcity" class="element text medium" style="font-size:18px;"/>
                                            <option value=""></option>
                                          <?php
                                            $result = mysql_query("SELECT code, `name` from city ") or die(mysql_error());

                                            while ($year = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                                                echo "<option value='$year[code]'>$year[name]</option>";
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                            </select>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><label class="description" for="element_1">State</label></td><td><select name="cmbstate" class="element text medium" style="font-size:18px;"/>
                                            <option value=""></option>
                                            <?php
                                            $result = mysql_query("SELECT code, `name` from state ") or die(mysql_error());

                                            while ($year = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                                                echo "<option value='$year[code]'>$year[name]</option>";
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                            </select>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><label class="description" for="element_1">Country</label></td><td><select name="cmbcount" class="element text medium" style="font-size:18px;"/>
                                            <option value=""></option>
                                            <?php
                                            $result = mysql_query("SELECT code, `name` from country ") or die(mysql_error());

                                            while ($year = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                                                echo "<option value='$year[code]'>$year[name]</option>";
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                            </select>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><label class="description" for="element_1">Telephone</label></td><td><input id="element_1" name="tel" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><label class="description" for="element_1">Mobile</label></td><td><input id="element_1" name="mob" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="10" value=""/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <br />
                                            </tr>

                                            </table>

                                            <tr>
                                                <br /><p style="border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;"></p><br />
                                                <div class="form_description">
                                                    <h2>Zimmedar Details</h2>

                                                </div>
                                            </tr>
                                            <table border="1px" id="zimtable" border="0px" size="100px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><strong>Zimmedar Name</strong></td>
                                                    <td><strong>Mobile</strong> </td>

                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><input name="zimname_0" type="text" id="zimname_0" size="40" maxlength="20" /></td>
                                                    <td><input name="zimmob_0" type="text" id="zimmob_0" size="13" maxlength="20" /></td>
                                                </tr>

                                            </table>
                                            <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addRow();" /><input name="h" type="hidden"   id="h" value="1" />
                                            <tr>
                                                <br /><p style="border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;"></p><br />
                                                <div class="form_description">
                                                    <h2>Muallim Details</h2>
                                                    <!--<p>This is your form description. Click here to edit.</p>-->
                                                </div>
                                            </tr>
                                            <table border="1px" id="alimtable" border="0px" size="100px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><strong>Muallim Name</strong></td>
                                                    <td><strong>Mobile</strong> </td>
                                                    <td><strong>Qabiliyat</strong> </td>

                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><input name="alimname_0" type="text" id="alimname_0" size="40" maxlength="20" /></td>
                                                    <td><input name="alimmob_0" type="text" id="alimmob_0" size="13" maxlength="20" /></td>
                                                    <td><select id="qabil_0" name="qabil_0" class="element text large" style="font-size:14px;"/>
                                                        <option value="MUFTI">MUFTI</option>
                                                        <option value="AALIM">AALIM</option>
                                                        <option value="QARI">QARI</option>
                                                        <option value="HAFIZ">HAFIZ</option>
                                                         </select></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                         <input name="r" type="hidden"  id="r" value="1" />
                                            </table>
                                            <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addalRow();" />



                                            <br /><p style="border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;"></p><br />
                                            <table border="0px" width="85%">
                                                <tbody><tr>
                                                        <td width="105"><label class="description">No. of Students</label></td>
                                                        <td width="65"><input type="text" name=stu" size="5" maxlength="5"></input></td>
                                                        <td width="105"><label class="description">No. of Batches</label></td><td width="14"><input type="text" name="batch" size="5" maxlength="3"></input></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"></input>

                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>



                                            </table>     
                                            </div>
                                            </div>




                                            </form>  

                                            </body>
                                            </html>
```

Comment: its just that i want to save my alim table rows to get saved into my database but since h is counter is shud increment by one but it shows the counter 12 wen i add a new row

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your problem is that you don't cast your strings as int. `+` can mean either concatenation or addition, depending on the types of the 2 variables it's used on.

For example:

```
var x = '1';
var y = 2;
alert(x+y); // 12, since x is a string and y is automatically cast to string.

alert(parseInt(x)+parseInt(y)) = 3; // since we cast both x and y to int.
```

**PS: If you really need help, and for anyone here to read your code, copy the important bits, not the whole file.**

PS2: You should start using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) - it can save you a lot of time